# Standard Commons Logging discovery in action with spring-jcl

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging

I have a springBoot all with these dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.28</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mashape.unirest/unirest-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mashape.unirest</groupId>
            <artifactId>unirest-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

but I have this message on the console:

```
Standard Commons Logging discovery in action with spring-jcl: please remove commons-logging.jar from classpath in order to avoid potential conflicts
```

Here the mvn dependency:tree :

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ----------------< com.planets:com.planets >-----------------
[INFO] Building planets 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]   from pom.xml
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- dependency:3.5.0:tree (default-cli) @ com.planets ---
[INFO] com.planets:com.planets:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:3.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:3.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.9.19:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:3.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.zaxxer:HikariCP:jar:5.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:6.0.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.orm:hibernate-core:jar:6.2.5.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- jakarta.persistence:jakarta.persistence-api:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- jakarta.transaction:jakarta.transaction-api:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.5.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:6.0.6.Final:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- io.smallrye:jandex:jar:3.0.5:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.14.5:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:jar:4.0.3:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-core:jar:4.0.3:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |     +- org.eclipse.angus:angus-activation:jar:2.0.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |     +- org.glassfish.jaxb:txw2:jar:4.0.3:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |     \- com.sun.istack:istack-commons-runtime:jar:4.1.2:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- jakarta.inject:jakarta.inject-api:jar:2.0.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  \- org.antlr:antlr4-runtime:jar:4.10.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:3.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:3.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:6.0.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:6.0.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:6.0.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:6.0.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:jar:2.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:2.0.7:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:6.0.10:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:jar:3.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:3.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:3.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:3.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:3.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.4.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.4.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.20.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.20.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:2.0.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.33:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:6.0.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:6.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:6.1.1:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:6.0.10:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:jar:3.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:10.1.10:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:8.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |     \- jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:jar:3.0.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:3.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:3.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.15.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.15.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.15.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:3.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:10.1.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:10.1.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:6.0.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.micrometer:micrometer-observation:jar:1.11.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- io.micrometer:micrometer-commons:jar:1.11.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:6.0.10:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.15.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.projectlombok:lombok:jar:1.18.28:provided
[INFO] +- com.mashape.unirest:unirest-java:jar:1.4.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.16:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.15:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpasyncclient:jar:4.1.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore-nio:jar:4.4.16:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:jar:4.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.json:json:jar:20160212:compile
[INFO] +- com.itextpdf:itextpdf:jar:5.5.13.3:compile
[INFO] +- com.mysql:mysql-connector-j:jar:8.0.33:runtime
[INFO] +- io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-api:jar:0.11.5:compile
[INFO] +- io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-impl:jar:0.11.5:runtime
[INFO] +- io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-jackson:jar:0.11.5:runtime
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.15.2:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.15.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:3.1.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:3.1.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:3.1.1:test
[INFO] |  +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.8.0:test
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:4.0.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  \- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:jar:2.1.2:runtime
[INFO] |  +- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.4.11:test
[INFO] |  |  \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:2.4.11:test
[INFO] |  |     \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:9.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.24.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest:jar:2.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:jar:5.9.3:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.9.3:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:jar:1.2.0:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:jar:1.9.3:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.2:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:jar:5.9.3:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:jar:5.9.3:test
[INFO] |  |     \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:jar:1.9.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:5.3.1:test
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.14.5:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:3.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:jar:5.3.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.5.1:test
[INFO] |  |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:6.0.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:6.0.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:6.0.10:test
[INFO] |  \- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:jar:2.9.1:test
[INFO] \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-test:jar:6.1.1:test
[INFO]    \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:6.1.1:compile
[INFO]       \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto:jar:6.1.1:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As illustrated in, for instance, [`camunda/zeebe` PR13300](https://github.com/camunda/zeebe/pull/13300):

> Spring displays a prominent warning when using different versions of `commons-logging`. They use their own variant, `spring-jcl`, and importing `commons-logging` conflicts with this.

So I would first try and exclude `commons-logging` from the project dependencies. This will force your application to use the logging system provided by Spring Boot Starter.

```xml
<dependencies>
    <!-- other dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <!-- other dependencies -->
</dependencies>
```

You might need to add similar exclusions to other dependencies if they also pull in commons-logging:

```bash
mvn dependency:tree | grep commons-logging
# or
mvn dependency:tree | findstr commons-logging
```

From your maven tree:

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mashape.unirest</groupId>
        <artifactId>unirest-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.9</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

---

[Shashwat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1213885/shashwat) asks:

> Is there any way to make springboot handle it without removing the conflicting entries?

While it is generally best to remove conflicting entries to make sure clarity and avoid potential issues, there are ways to work around the conflict without removing the `commons-logging` dependency. Spring Boot can manage logging through `spring-jcl` even if `commons-logging` is present, as long as you properly configure the logging system.

Spring Boot can use [SLF4J](https://www.slf4j.org/) for logging. You can bridge `commons-logging` to SLF4J to make sure all logging goes through the same channel. To do this, include the `jcl-over-slf4j` dependency in your project:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
    <version>YourSLF4JVersion</version>
</dependency>
```

That dependency replaces `commons-logging` at runtime with a version that delegates to SLF4J.

Or: You can customize the logging configuration in Spring Boot by adding a [`logback.xml` or `logback-spring.xml` file](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-logging#logback-configuration-logging) in your `src/main/resources` directory. That file allows you to define how logging should be handled, including the integration of various logging frameworks.

If you still encounter issues, you can conditionally exclude `commons-logging` only if it is causing conflicts. That can be achieved by analyzing the project's dependency tree and applying exclusions specifically where conflicts occur.

Comment: I've tried wit the same error: MacBook-Pro planets % mvn dependency:tree | grep commons-logging
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile

Comment: @NunyetdeCanCalçada Can you check the line before this one, in the mvn dependency:tree out, which imports the common-logging? It should be a `some.group:some-artifact:jar:1.0.0:compile`, and you would need to exclude commons-logging from `some.group:some-artifact`.

Comment: @NunyetdeCanCalçada I have updated the answer to take into account your last edit and your maven depdency tree.

Comment: Is there any way to make springboot handle it without removing the conflicting entries?

Answer (score 3):

In your case `unirest-java` has a transitive dependency on `org.apache.httpcomponents`, which further has a transitive dependency on `commons-logging`. Spring JCL probably scans the classpath, finds `commons-logging` and that's why it warns you about potential conflicts with Spring Boot's pre-configured loggers.

You can list all the dependencies and transitive dependencies in your Maven project by running `mvn dependency:tree`. For Gradle projects you can run `gradle dependencies`.

To exclude `commons-logging` in a Maven project, add this to your `pom.xml` configuration file:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mashape.unirest</groupId>
        <artifactId>unirest-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.9</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

If you're using Gradle, add this to your `build.gradle` file:

```
implementation('com.mashape.unirest:unirest-java:1.4.9') {
        exclude group: 'commons-logging', module: 'commons-logging'
    }
```

You may also exclude dependencies globally from your project:

```
configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
    all {
        exclude group: 'commons-logging', module: 'commons-logging'
    }
}
```

Comment: I would use `configureEach` instead of `all` in Gradle (new Tasks API).

Answer (score 0):

can you please try the below exclusion for maven you have in dependency tree.

```
<project>
    <!-- ... other project configurations ... -->

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Add your other dependencies here -->

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Add other build plugins here -->
            <plugin>
                <!-- Use maven-dependency-plugin to exclude commons-logging -->
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>exclude-commons-logging</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>purge-local-repository</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                            <version>1.2</version>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>*</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was too lazy to exclude this dependency manually one by one, so this is how I fixed this using Gradle in a more efficient way. Just put below in your Gradle config to exclude this transitive dependency (so that only `spring-jcl` is used at runtime).

For `build.gradle.kts`:

```kotlin
configurations {
    runtimeOnly {
        exclude(group = "commons-logging", module = "commons-logging")
    }
}
```

Or, if you use `build.gradle` / groovy syntax:

```
configurations {
    runtime {
        exclude(group = "org.slf4j", module = "slf4j-log4j12")
    }
}
```

Comment: Neither `runtime` nor `runtimeOnly` worked for me. I had to use `all` or `configureEach`.